# Организация сокет-сервера

Tags: многопоточность, сервер, клиент-сервер

Стоит задача, спроектировать сервер построенный на сокетах, при условии, что он будет работать в режиме непрерывного общения клиента с сервером. Под непрерывным общением я подразумеваю, то что между клиентом и сервером установится соединение и они по очереди будут писать и читать в потоки ввода/вывода.

Текущие соображения такие: есть вечный цикл который принимает соединения и закидывает их в какой-нибудь список. Затем есть несколько потоков, которые постоянно обходят этот список и ищут соединения, в потоке ввода которых есть непрочитанные байты. Затем они отдают эти соединения на обработку пулу потоков-`worker`'ов.

Адекватная ли и эффективная ли такая организация сервера? (Немного размытый вопрос, но тем не менее). Мне ужасно не нравится момент, в котором есть несколько потоков мониторящих соединения на ввод, что-то в них не так.

Comment: Между клиентом и сервером напишите службу, которая будет стартовать по крону, забирать поток с сервера и направлять клиенту и слать ответы обратно

Answer (score 1):

Предложу немного другую реализацию, более классическую:

В бесконечном цикле работает только прослушивание подключений. Сокет, создаваемый для каждого нового подключения, передаётся в функцию-обработчик, запускаемую в отдельном потоке для каждого нового подключения. В функции же, также в бесконечном цикле, ведётся общение с клиентом путём поочерёдной отправки данных и их считывания.

Таким образом, имеем:

1. По одному потоку на каждого подключённого клиента
2. Немедленный ответ на подключение
3. Логически раздельная обработка сообщений каждого отдельного клиента

Предложенный Вами подход эффективен с точки зрения экономии потоков, т.к. в Вашем случае, если я всё верно понял, потоки запускаются только тогда, когда есть данные на обработку. Однако такая реализация более запутана логически, что может породить проблемы при отладке и использовании.

Comment: Изначально так и хотел сделать, но вот именно из-за того, что при 1000 клиентов онлайн будет 1000 потоков, призадумался...

Comment: @wcobalt Если мне память не изменяет, в примере реализации клиент-серверного чата в документации к `boost.Asio` был использован именно такой классический подход. А уж они-то должны знать толк в этом. Тем более, если у Вас в просматривающем потоке возникнет исключение, просматривать станет некому. Да и в классической реализации быстрый ответ сервера более вероятен.